# RuntimeError: run loop already started

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to connect my `page.py` to `reg.py` so that when I click on the register button it directly pops up the `reg.py` window.

**PAGE.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime, QDate, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType
from LANDING import Ui_LandingPage
import pyttsx3 
import speech_recognition as sr 
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os
from requests import get
import pywhatkit as kit
import sys 
import pyjokes
import time
import pyautogui
from register import Ui_register


engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')  
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')

# print(voices[0].id)
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)
engine.setProperty('rate',170)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

class MainThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainThread,self).__init__()
        
       
    
    def run(self):
        self.TaskExecution()
        
    
    
    def TaskExecution(self):
        speak('Welcome To Jarvis World')
        speak('Im Your Personal Assistan')
        speak('If you already have account then click on login button')
        speak('If you want to register your self then click on register button')
    

        
startExecution = MainThread()

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_LandingPage()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.register) 
        self.ui.movie = QtGui.QMovie("C:/Users/OZZYY/Downloads/cyber-artificialintelligence.gif")
        self.ui.label_9.setMovie(self.ui.movie)
        self.ui.movie.start()
        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.start(1000)
        startExecution.start() 
 
    def register(self):
        import reg
       


        
        

    
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
page = Main()
page.show()
exit(app.exec_())
```

**REG.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime, QDate, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType
from register import Ui_register
import pyttsx3 
import speech_recognition as sr 
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
from requests import get
import pywhatkit as kit
import sys 
import pyjokes
import time
import pyautogui
import csv
import json
import pandas as pd




engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')

print(voices[0].id)
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)
engine.setProperty('rate',165)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()




class MainThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainThread,self).__init__()
    
    def run(self):
        self.TaskExecution()    
    
    
    def TaskExecution(self):
        speak('Welcome To Registration Page')
        speak('Type Your Name Then Press Tab')
        speak('Type Your Age Then Press Tab')
        speak('Type Your Email')  
        speak('Then Click on face biometric verification and wait.') 
        speak('Then Register Yourself!')    
        
        
startExecution = MainThread()
 
class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_register()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        # self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.loading_data,saving_data) 
        self.ui.movie = QtGui.QMovie("C:/Users/OZZYY/Downloads/facereg.gif")
        self.ui.label_5.setMovie(self.ui.movie)
        self.ui.movie.start()
        startExecution.start()    

      
 
        
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
page = Main()
page.show()
exit(app.exec_())
```

This is the error I get when connecting the push button:

```
*QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\login-verification-master\reg.py", line 54, in run
    self.TaskExecution()
  File "d:\login-verification-master\reg.py", line 58, in TaskExecution
    speak('Welcome To Registration Page')
  File "d:\login-verification-master\reg.py", line 44, in speak
    engine.runAndWait()
  File "C:\python 3.10\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 177, in runAndWait
    raise RuntimeError('run loop already started')
RuntimeError: run loop already started*
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that both, `PAGE.py` and `REG.py` claim to be the main program, i.e. they both want to start the main event loop. Remove

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
page = Main()
page.show()
exit(app.exec_())
```

from `REG.py` and try again.

(There might be other issues as well.)

Comment: can you give me more information or can you correct the whole code please?

Comment: @HuzaifKhan In a Qt-Application there can only ever be one instance of `QApplication` running (the `.exec_` method). Your code instantiates two instances, one in `PAGE.py` and another one in `REG.py`. Remove the lines I quoted in my answer from `REG.py` and run your program.

Comment: The best solution is to always have those lines in an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.

Comment: when i run program after remove 
 app = QApplication(sys.argv)
page = Main()
page.show()
exit(app.exec_())

it from reg,py its not working